# VB.Net and Access - Getting Totaliser Value

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access

I'm trying to databind a textbox to a totaliser value in an access database. I currently update the database via `OleDbCommand` and then edit any existing entries via databinding on the form.

I have everything working fine, but I want a textbox to show the totaliser (sum) of a particular column in the datbase. Access shows this totaliser underneath the column if the database is opened.

Is there a method to bind this value to the textbox?

Thanks

Comment: If you are binding the data to properties, you can use Linq if you have all of the column's data for the sum.. If not, I guess you could run a separate query to retrieve the `SUM` from Access and display it in the Textbox

Comment: Can you give me an example of this please? I struggle with database's and gridviews ect. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, however you are accessing the database, you need to make a call to get the `SUM` of your desired table.

If we are talking about `SQL`, it would look something like:

`conn = New OleDbConnection(Get_Constring)
    conn.Open()
    cmd.Connection = conn
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    sSQL = " SELECT SUM(total) AS Total From YourTable"
    cmd.CommandText = sSQL
    OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    If dr.Read() Then
        set total = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Total"])
    End If`

You could load this into a `DataTable`/`DataSet` or use the `DataReader` and assign the result (the sum) to a textbox, like:

`TextBox1.Text = total`

If you are using `Linq` it could look like (this is just an example):

```
Dim yourObject = From cust In db.Customers
                             Group By cust.City
                             Into Average(cust.Orders.Count)
                             Order By Average

DataGridView1.DataSource = yourObject
```